# .NET Core Identity Server dynamic Client app registration and authentication

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have created an Identity Server using .NET Core and IdentityServer4, I have set of APIs and all calls to these APIs must be authenticated but these APIs might be used by third-party applications so clients can be dynamic
Till now example I am finding is set Clients on startup statically like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddIdentityServer()
   .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
   .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
   .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
}

public class Config
{
   public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
   {
       return new List<ApiResource>
       {
           new ApiResource("resourceApi1", "API Application1")
           new ApiResource("resourceApi2", "API Application2")
       };
   }

   public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
   {
       return new List<Client>
       {
           new Client
           {
               ClientId = "clientApp1",

               // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

               // secret for authentication
               ClientSecrets =
               {
                   new Secret("secret".Sha256())
               },

               AllowedScopes = { "resourceApi1" }
           }
       };
   }
}
```

Is there a way in IdentityServer implementation to register Client Apps and set dynamically
For Example, If I have APIs
1. resourceApi1
2. resourceApi2

Each third-party APIs should be able to register and we should be able to generate ClientID and Client secret for each with what resources they can access and Identity Server authenticates that ClientID and Client Secret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option to use a client store. By default identity server uses in memory store for finding clients:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(Clients)
```

You can change this and register your own client store

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddClientStore<MyClientStore>()
```

and implement the service

```
class MyClientStore : IClientStore
{
    public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
    {

    }
}
```

This would solve dynamic lookup of clients. For registration of clients and their management, you would need to implement your own infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't knowing this, AddInMemoryApiResources can be changed? and for a Client app, we need to restrict access to only few controllers (Maybe by scope) in the client store is it possible?

Comment: For API resources there is `.AddResourceStore<T>()` method.

Comment: `Client` class has `AllowedScopes` property, it can be part of the client store.

Answer (score 1):

First of all configure your [IdentityServer using EntityFramework](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/reference/ef.html#entity-framework-support), Then you need to some Apis to add Client and  ApiResources.

IdentityServer has its own implementation of *Stores* using EntityFramework.

You can add new Api for this purpose.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class DynamicController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ConfigurationDbContext context;

    public DynamicController(ConfigurationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddApiResource(ApiResource apiResource)
    {
        context.ApiResources.Add(apiResource);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddClient(Client client)
    {
        context.Clients.Add(client);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```